# How do I search for a string in a list within an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search

I have created an array with the datatype List as show here:

```
List<string>[] phase2 = new List<string>[200];
```

With quite a few initializations (here is a quick example):

```
    phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
    phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Jim", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[3] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[4] = new List<string>() { "Robert", "Complex", "A", "PL", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
```

I was wondering how I would search for the string "B", in index 3, of all of the arrays I have Initialized?

Also as a bonus (not sure if this is possible) could you search for MULTIPLE strings in DIFFERENT indexes? For example I want to return all the lists that have a string value of "B" in index 3, and a string value of "Yes" in Index 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses! I haven't learned about linq yet, so much of the answers were over my head. Thanks to lollercoasters for the dumbed down solution :)

Comment: Have you tried any approach , please present any solution that you may have attempted and which might be giving you some problem....

Comment: Will you query multiple times this structure? I mean the array of lists ... will it be cached?

Comment: Try `phase2.Where(x => x[2] == "B" && x[4] == "Yes");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like a non-Linq lambda solution that you can understand better, here you go mate:

```
List<string>[] phase2 = new List<string>[200];
phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Jim", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
phase2[3] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
phase2[4] = new List<string>() { "Robert", "Complex", "A", "PL", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };

for (int i = 0; i < phase2.Length; i++)
{
  var list = phase2[i];
  if (list == null) continue; // skip empty lists
  if (list[2] == "B" && list[4] == "Yes")
  {
    // found elements in list
    Console.WriteLine("found elements in list at index: " + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I display the contents of the list at the specified index that is shown? Sorry I didn't get back to ya right away.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you mean list[i] ?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the LINQ way of doing it:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string>[] phase2 = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<string>(), 200).ToArray();

    phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
    phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Jim", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[3] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[4] = new List<string>() { "Robert", "Complex", "A", "PL", "zNO", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };

    List<string>[] result = phase2?.Where(x => x.Any(y => y == "B")).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, remember that each element in phase2 is a list, so it implements Enumerable, so that opens up all the LINQ capabilities on it. 
Find comes to mind immediately, with a function (predicate) you provide.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2

If you research this avenue, you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to search for all the lists that have an element that match your argument like so:

```
phase2.Where(list => list.Any(item => item == "string to search for"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a class that could help you:

```
public class ListFilterer
{
    private readonly List<string>[] _searchSpace;

    public ListFilterer(List<string>[] searchSpace)
        => this._searchSpace = searchSpace ?? new List<string>[0];

    public IEnumerable<List<string>> GetListsHaving(params Tuple<int, string>[] query)
        => (from l in _searchSpace
            where AllConditionsMatch(l, query)
            select l);

    private static bool AllConditionsMatch(IReadOnlyList<string> lst, IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>> conditions)
    {
        foreach (var cond in conditions)
        {
            if (cond.Item1 < 0 || cond.Item1 > lst.Count - 1)
                return false;

            if (lst[cond.Item1] != cond.Item2)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```